# Ionic Toggle returning wrong value

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I made this simple test with ionic toggle but my alert return False when is True and True when is false. Any ideas?

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jtKCf


$scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
    alert('Push Notification Change: '+ $scope.pushNotification.checked);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine this just happens to be a tedious timing issue.  [The official example here suffers the same issue as yours if you look at the console log it outputs](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tfAzj).

[Here is a CodePen I made that works](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/iwuvC) using `$timeout` that solves this issue.

```
$scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        alert('Push Notification Change: '+ $scope.pushNotification.checked);
    }, 0);
};
```

/edit

[Here is another working approach that I made](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/vzAth) after seeing tasseKATT's comment.

```
$scope.$watch('pushNotification.checked', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('Push Notification Change: ' + newValue);
});
```

You can avoid needing the `ng-change` using this alternative approach.

Comment: @PedroMarques I voted ya up, this issue is a sneaky one.  I'm not sure if you can accept answers yet but when you have that ability please accept, thanks!

Comment: Ionic uses a lot of `setTimeout` internally which causes things like this. Instead of using `$timeout` to put something at the end of the browser event queue, skip `ng-change` entirely and use `$watch` to get notified when the value actually changes.

Comment: @tasseKATT Thanks, I updated the answer providing this alternative approach.

Comment: No problem :) +1 from me.